# Elasticsearch exact match of specific field

Tags: elasticsearch

Using

```
$ docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
```

Populate db

```
$ curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "text": "foo bar"
}
'

$ curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/2" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "text":   "baz quix"
}
'
```

Validate that db was populated

```
$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'

{"took":48,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_type","_id":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":
{
  "text":   "baz quix"
}
},{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_type","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":
{
  "text": "foo bar"
}
}]}}
```

`constant_score` returns `[]`, though expected to return object with id `2`

```
$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "text":"baz quix"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

{"took":14,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

`filtered` is not supported at all

```
$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "text":"baz quix"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":4,"col":17}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":4,"col":17},"status":400}
```

Neither search without `constant_score` not working

```
$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text":"baz quix"
    }
  }
}'

{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text":"baz quix"
    }
  }
}'

{"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, examine the mapping of your index:

```
$ curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping'

{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "text": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In that output you can see that Elasticsearch by default maps your field twice: it creates field named `"text"` with `"type": "text"` and nested field named `"text.keyword"` with `"type": "keyword"`.

Fields with type `text` are full text fields, which data are [analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) while indexing, and fields with type `keyword` persist their data in index "as is" without being analyzed.

So in your case for term query you must use nested field with type `keyword`:

```
$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "text.keyword": "baz quix"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

{"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_type","_id":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":{"text":"baz quix"}}]}}
```

Also you can read section "Why doesn’t the term query match my document?" in [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html), which also provides clean explanation.

Comment: tnx, `text` field was created as multifield https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: @srghma, yes, it's default elasticsearch behavior when you don't provide mapping for index explicitly.